# Our prof says for a double loop, T(n) is a*(n^2) + b*n + c. I think it's just a*(n^2). What's the exact answer?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is the slide by our prof.

Example 4: Consider this simple program:

```
s = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
  for j = 1 to n do
    s= s+i+j
  endfor
endfor
```

`T(n) = ?`

It's hard to get the exact expression of T(n) even for this very simple program.
We can see: the loop iterates `n²` times, and loop body takes
constant number of instructions. So `T(n) = a*(n^2) + bn + c` for some constants a, b, c.

Now here's what I think. Let's assume that the body loop takes constant time 'a'. Then that itself will be looped over for a*(n^2) times. So, I don't understand from where b*n + c comes! What's the actual answer?

Comment: If there is a very hard calculation outside of inner-loop but inside outer-loop, b*n is important.

Comment: You haven't considered the cost of the loop constructs themselves...

Comment: s=0 also takes time. It's simply better to be on safe side than to guess that lower order terms do not exist. an^2 + bn + c subsumes an^2.

Comment: Java vs Assembly : c constant makes difference for low iterations.

Comment: But with a good optimizer... O(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things that happen once: setting `s` to 0 and setting `i` to 1.

Things that happen n times: incrementing `i`, checking whether `i` is less than `n`, setting `j` to 1, jumping back to line 2.

Things that happen `n^2` times: incrementing `j`, checking whether `j` is less than `n`, calculating `s+i+j` and storing the result in `s`, jumping to line 3.

Answer (score 1):

(a*(n^2) + b*n + c) / (a*(n^2)) = 1 + b/(a*n) + c/(a*(n^2)) -> 1 as n -> infinity.

Comment: Good approach. C dies first, then b dies.